# Merge multiple csv files to one csv file in Azure Blob Storage using pyspark

Tags: azure, pyspark, azure-blob-storage, azure-databricks

I am using below code to save the csv files back to blob storage, though it is creating multiple files as it runs in loop. Now I would like to merge them into one single csv file. Though I have used dbutils.fs.cp/mv, it is not helpful

```
while start_date <= end_date:
df = spark.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").options(header="true", inferschema="true").load(inputFilePath)
df.coalesce(1).write.mode("append").option("header","true").format("com.databricks.s`park.csv").save(TargetPath)`
```

A similar request has been posted below, but it has been done using pandas data frame and I am looking something with spark dataframe.
"[Copy data from multiple csv files into one csv file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56767724/copy-data-from-multiple-csv-files-into-one-csv-file)"

Comment: whats the while loop doing here? because on every iteration it creates a new df and if `inputFilePath` is the path to file not the directory, only one file is read at a time.

Comment: @Waqas - Based on start dates and end dates it would loop and reads the file one at a time. Is there any better way of getting this done?

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion would be, use while loop to create a list of csv files to read and then use spark csv readers to read them all at once. For example:

```
files = []
while start_date <= end_date:
    files.append(inputFilePath)


df = spark.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").options(header="true", inferschema="true").csv(files)

df.coalesce(1).write.mode("append").option("header","true").format("com.databricks.spark.csv").save(TargetPath)
```

Comment: glad that it helped